# How I use relationship in blade template (hasOne) || Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, has-one

Okay i'm trying get "likes" and "users" in Posts by relationship hasOne.

here is my `Post.php` Model
    class Posts extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
}

public function Like()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Like::class, 'post_id', 'id');
}}
```

My Blade template

```
@foreach ($showdeals as $deal)


                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="profiletimeline">

                                            {{$deal->like->status}}
                                            <br>
                                            {{$deal->user->email}}

                        <div class="sl-item">
                            <div class="sl-left"> <img src=" {{asset( '/assets/images/users/2.jpg')}}" alt="user" class="img-circle"> </div>
                            <div class="sl-right">
                                <div> <a href="#" class="link">{{$deal->user->username}}</a> || {{$deal->subject}} <Br> <span class="sl-date">{{$deal->created_at}}</span>
                                    <div class="m-t-20 row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12"><img src="{{$deal->image}}" alt="user" class="img-responsive radius"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
                                            <p> {{$deal->body}} </p> <a href="{{$deal->link}}" class="btn btn-success"> עבור למוצר </a></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="like-comm m-t-20"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link m-r-10">2 תגובות</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link m-r-10"><i class="fa fa-heart text-danger"></i> 5 לייקים</a> </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>




                    </div>
                    <hr></div>
            </div>

                @endforeach
```

And there is my Controller

class PostsController extends Controller
{

```
public function showdeals()
{

    $showdeals = Posts::with( 'User', 'Like')->get();
        return view('posts.show', compact('showdeals'));
}




public function helpnewview(){
    return view('posts.anew');
}


public function helpnew(Request $request){
    //User pick link
    $userlink = $request['userlink'];
    return \Redirect::route('newdeal', compact('userlink'));
}



public function new(Request $request)
{
    //Emdeb user link
    $link = Embed::create($request['userlink']);
    $linke = $request['userlink'];
    return view('posts.new', compact('link', 'userlink', 'linke'));
}




public function create(Request $request)
{

    $posts = New Posts;
    $posts->user_id = Auth::User()->id;
    $posts->subject = $request['subject'];
    $posts->body = $request['body'];
    $posts->link = $request['link'];
    $posts->price = $request['price'];
    $posts->image = $request['image'];
    $posts->tag = $request['tag'];
    $posts->save();

    return back();
}
```

}

Now if I do something like `{{$deal->user->email}}` its will work,
if I go to something like this `{{$deal->like->status}}` its does not work,
am I missing something ?

Comment: I see a lot of capital letter issues, dunno if that might be messing up your code

Comment: no its good, also without capital words its the same.

Comment: and also with `{{$deal->like}}` I get `{"id":1,"user_id":1,"post_id":1,"status":0,"created_at":"2018-02-09 20:19:30","updated_at":"2018-02-09 20:19:30"} `

Comment: You were just fetching the relationships the wrong way, look at the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want [multiple relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to be eagerly loaded you need to use an array of relationships: `Model::with(['rl1', 'rl2'])->get();`

```
public function showdeals()
{
    ...
    $showdeals = Posts::with(['User', 'Like'])->get();
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:**

From that `json` in the comments that I see, there is no attribute named `status` in your `Like` model so thats probably the root of the problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I add "[]" and its still the same.
with `{{$deal->like}}` I get `{"id":1,"user_id":1,"post_id":1,"status":0,"created_at":"2018-02-09 20:19:30","updated_at":"2018-02-09 20:19:30"} `

Comment: Can you include your `Like` model in your question too?

Comment: From that `json` you posted it seems like your `Like` model doesn't have a `status` property @LielDahan

Comment: it has a"status:0"

Comment: So is it throwing an error or that field is empty when you print in the html?

Comment: Yes it's says that id for example doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Controller edit this code

```
  public function showdeals()
 {
        $showdeals = Posts::all();
        return view('posts.show', compact('showdeals'));
 }
```

And blade file code

```
 @foreach ($showdeals as $deal)
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="profiletimeline">

                                        {{ $deal->Like->status }}
                                        <br>
                                        {{ $deal->User->email }}

   @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is good except

> {{$deal->like->status}} 
>  {{$deal->user->email}}

Please try as

```
{{$deal->Like()->status}} 
<br> 
{{$deal->User()->email}}
```